# Using HXT with an XML document including a specification header

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

I'd like to iron out a bug the the [rdf4h](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rdf4h) library that I currently maintain. It supports parsing XML/RDF documents in to RDF graphs in the [XmlParser](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rdf4h-1.2.1/docs/Text-RDF-RDF4H-XmlParser.html) module, but does not successfully parse XML/RDF documents that include an XML specification header, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

The parser uses HXT arrow interface, namely the `Text.XML.HXT.Core` [module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.0.0/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Core.html). I have boiled the problem down to two parsing attempts made in the functions `testSuccess` and `testFailure`. Both use [runSLA](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.1/docs/Control-Arrow-StateListArrow.html#v%3arunSLA). The author of hxt tells me that the problem lies in the use of `xread` , and that I should first of all be extracting the XML document from the string before `xread`. (Unfortunately, he hasn't responded on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/UweSchmidt/hxt/issues/4) I raised about this).

Below, there are two strings, both containing the same XML document. The `xmlDoc1` string includes a specification header, which trips up the `xread` arrow in `testFailure`.

```hs
module HXTProblem where

import Text.XML.HXT.Core

data GParseState = GParseState { stateGenId :: Int } deriving(Show)

-- this document has an XML specification included
xmlDoc1 :: String
xmlDoc1 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>" ++
          "<shiporder orderid=\"889923\" " ++
          "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " ++
          "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"shiporder.xsd\">" ++
          "<orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>" ++
             "<shipto>" ++
               "<name>Ola Nordmann</name>" ++
             "</shipto>" ++
          "</shiporder>"

-- this document does not include the XML specification
xmlDoc2 :: String
xmlDoc2 = "<shiporder orderid=\"889923\" " ++
          "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " ++
          "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"shiporder.xsd\">" ++
          "<orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>" ++
             "<shipto>" ++
               "<name>Ola Nordmann</name>" ++
             "</shipto>" ++
          "</shiporder>"

initState :: GParseState
initState = GParseState { stateGenId = 0 }

-- | Works
testSuccess :: (GParseState,[XmlTree])
testSuccess = runSLA xread initState xmlDoc2

{- output of runnnig testSuccess
(GParseState {stateGenId = 0},[NTree (XTag "shiporder" [NTree (XAttr "orderid") [NTree (XText "889923") []],NTree (XAttr "xmlns:xsi") [NTree (XText "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance") []],NTree (XAttr "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation") [NTree (XText "shiporder.xsd") []]]) [NTree (XTag "orderperson" []) [NTree (XText "John Smith") []],NTree (XTag "shipto" []) [NTree (XTag "name" []) [NTree (XText "Ola Nordmann") []]]]]
-}

-- | Does not work
testFailure :: (GParseState,[XmlTree])
testFailure = runSLA xread initState xmlDoc1

{- ERROR running testFailure
(GParseState {stateGenId = 0},[NTree (XError 2 "\"string: \"<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"ISO-8859-1...\"\" (line 1, column 6):\nunexpected xml\nexpecting legal XML name character\n") []])
-}
```

I should add that I am looking for a solution using `runSLA` that will generate the same `XMLTree` when parsing either `xmlDoc1` or `xmlDoc2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hurray, this is been solved. The author of the HXT library has addressed the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/UweSchmidt/hxt/issues/4) added a new parser `xreadDoc` in [this commit](https://github.com/UweSchmidt/hxt/commit/171decf4ad476e3ea759e3d218aa0c663942a551). I've fixed the rdf4h library version 1.2.2 and up, using this new parser in [this commit](https://github.com/robstewart57/rdf4h/commit/bbb78e60b72158e285f19a2c2ab058cc68755988), so XML/RDF documents (with spec and encoding headings) can now be parsed with the `XmlParser`.

Note the new arrow composition in `testFailure`, as `(xreadDoc >>> isElem)`.

```hs
module HXTProblem where

import Text.XML.HXT.Core

data GParseState = GParseState { stateGenId :: Int } deriving(Show)

-- this document has an XML specification included
xmlDoc1 :: String
xmlDoc1 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>" ++
          "<shiporder orderid=\"889923\" " ++
          "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " ++
          "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"shiporder.xsd\">" ++
          "<orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>" ++
             "<shipto>" ++
               "<name>Ola Nordmann</name>" ++
             "</shipto>" ++
          "</shiporder>"

-- this document does not include the XML specification
xmlDoc2 :: String
xmlDoc2 = "<shiporder orderid=\"889923\" " ++
          "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " ++
          "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"shiporder.xsd\">" ++
          "<orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>" ++
             "<shipto>" ++
               "<name>Ola Nordmann</name>" ++
             "</shipto>" ++
          "</shiporder>"

initState :: GParseState
initState = GParseState { stateGenId = 0 }

-- | Works
testSuccess :: (GParseState,[XmlTree])
testSuccess = runSLA xread initState xmlDoc2

-- | Does also now work!
testFailure :: (GParseState,[XmlTree])
testFailure = runSLA (xreadDoc >>> isElem) initState xmlDoc1

testEquality :: Bool
testEquality =
    let (_,x) = testSuccess
        (_,y) = testFailure
    in x == y
```